# force drop event in preload draggable elements (or work around)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I wrote the code below to generate a GUI to sort some data and it works very well, but, when I preload some data in the output fields (topSlot or bottomSlot), I wanted the drop event to be applied (and the stripes effects applied).

How the code works:

1. Elements are dragged from the right column to the top or bottom div
2. When dropped into the top div, the element in the right column gets a stripe in the top and is forbidden from being dropped again into the top div (the same happens when the element is dropped into the bottom div)
3. To return the element to the right column, just drag it out of the new container

Eager for answers.

Grateful,

jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/xfhvdz5g/1/

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="top">
            top
            <div id="topSlot" half="top">
                <div id="test1"><h2>test1</h2></div>
                <div id="test2"><h2>test2</h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            bottom
            <div id="bottomSlot" half="bottom">
                <div id="test2"><h2>test2</h2></div>
                <div id="test3"><h2>test3</h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
        <div id="elements">
            <div id="test1"><h2>test1</h2></div>
            <div id="test2"><h2>test2</h2></div>
            <div id="test3"><h2>test3</h2></div>
            <div id="foo1"><h2>foo1</h2></div>
            <div id="foo2"><h2>foo2</h2></div>
            <div id="foo3"><h2>foo3</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 460px;
}

#top {
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
}

#bottom {
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 1px dotted #CCCCCC;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 460px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

#topSlot, #bottomSlot
{
    min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #fffccf;
}

#elements {
  background-color: #cfffcf;
}

#elements div
{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    background-image: url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0067/0133/diagonal_red_stripes_copy_shop_preview.png");
    background-position-y: 200%;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#elements > div').each(function(i, j) {
  var oldId = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).addClass('correct').attr('header', '0').attr('id', oldId).appendTo('#elements').draggable({
    stack: '#elements div',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  })
});

$('#topSlot, #bottomSlot').droppable({
  accept: "#elements div",

  drop: function(event, ui)
  {
    var myId = $(this).attr('half');
    var element = $(ui.draggable);
    var draggableBottom = $(ui.draggable).attr('bottom');
    var draggableTop = $(ui.draggable).attr('top');


    if ((myId == "top") && (draggableTop != "1")) {
      $(ui.draggable).attr("top", "1");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      $(this).find('*').attr("pos", "top");

      var draggableBottom = $(ui.draggable).attr('bottom');
      var draggableTop = $(ui.draggable).attr('top');
      console.log("draggableTop" + draggableTop);
      console.log("draggableBottom" + draggableBottom);

      if ((draggableTop == "1") && (draggableBottom == "1")) {
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-position-y", "0");
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-size", "100% 100%");
        $(ui.draggable).draggable('disable');
      } else if (draggableTop == "1") {
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-position-y", "0");
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-size", "100% 50%");
      } else {
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-position-y", "100%");
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-size", "100% 50%");
      }
    } else if ((myId == "bottom") && (draggableBottom != "1")) {
      $(ui.draggable).attr("bottom", "1");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
      $(this).find('*').attr("pos", "bottom");

      var draggableBottom = $(ui.draggable).attr('bottom');
      var draggableTop = $(ui.draggable).attr('top');
      console.log("draggableTop" + draggableTop);
      console.log("draggableBottom" + draggableBottom);

      if ((draggableTop == "1") && (draggableBottom == "1")) {
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-position-y", "0");
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-size", "100% 100%");
        $(ui.draggable).draggable('disable');
      } else if (draggableTop == "1") {
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-position-y", "0");
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-size", "100% 50%");
      } else {
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-position-y", "100%");
        $(ui.draggable).css("background-size", "100% 50%");
      }
    }



  }
});

$('#topSlot, #bottomSlot').sortable({
  scroll: false
}, {
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    sortableIn = 1;
    $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({
      "opacity": "1.0",
      "transform": "scale(1.0)"
    });
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    sortableIn = 1;
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      revert: '100'
    });
    $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({
      "opacity": "1.0",
      "transform": "scale(1.0)"
    });
  },
  out: function(event, ui) {
    sortableIn = 0;
    $("#sortable").sortable({
      revert: false
    });
    $(".ui-sortable-helper").css({
      "opacity": "0.3",
      "transform": "scale(0.8)"
    });
  },
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    var pos = ui.position,
      top = pos.top,
      left = pos.left,
      item = ui.item,
      width = item.css("width"),
      height = item.css("height");

    if (sortableIn == 0) {

      ui.item.attr("style", ui.item.attr("style") + " " +
        "position: absolute; " +
        "top: " + top + "px; " +
        "height: " + height + "px; " +
        "width: " + width + "; " +
        "left: " + left + "px; ");
      ui.item.css({
        "transform": "scale(0.0)"
      }).animate({
        opacity: "0.0"
      }, '300', function() {

        var origem = $(ui.item).attr('pos');
        var elementId = $(ui.item).attr('id');

        $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).draggable('enable');


        var draggableBottom = $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).attr('bottom');
        var draggableTop = $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).attr('top');


        if (origem == "bottom" && draggableTop == "1") {
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).css("background-position-y", "0");
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).css("background-size", "100% 50%");
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).removeAttr("bottom");
        } else if (origem == "top" && draggableBottom == "1") {
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).css("background-position-y", "100%");
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).css("background-size", "100% 50%");
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).removeAttr("top");
        } else {
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).css("background-position-y", "200%");
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).removeAttr("top");
          $('#elements').find('#' + elementId).removeAttr("bottom");
        }

        $(ui.draggable).remove();

      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You probably want to load the data from a store(eg localStorage) and apply the effect from there. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: I tried using a hidden div with a date attribute containing all the ids of the preloaded elements and a javascript function to append the divs but it did not work out. 
I believe I should pass the ids on a function that triggers a drop event but I'm not sure how to do it..